# How to cut object with text mesh

Tags: modifiers

[image]

I want to delete everything from the patterned object lying outside of the text
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried the Knife Project tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its an option to lose the abilty to edit the Text, one of the easyest ways to doo this would be converting the text to a mesh and use the boolean modifier on the grid with the text as the intersecting object.[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it with a project knife. but it also helps